Can't send a message send a message from DLQ in Payara, I get a javax.jms.IllegalStateException: MQJMSRA_DS4001: commit():Illegal for a non-transacted
I'm using Payara 5.2022.5
public void resubmitMessages(boolean resubmitAll) throws Exception {
    log.debug("DLQService: resubmitMessages()");
    InitialContext ctx = null;
    QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    QueueConnection queueConn = null;

    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup("jms/ConnectionFactory");
        queueConn = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
        queueConn.start();

        Session session =  queueConn.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
        assert session.getTransacted();

        Queue clsQueue = (Queue) ctx.lookup("queue/main");
        MessageProducer sender = session.createProducer(clsQueue);
        assert session.getTransacted();

        Queue dlq = (Queue) ctx.lookup("queue/mq.sys.dmq");
        MessageConsumer dlqConsumer = session.createConsumer(dlq);
        assert session.getTransacted();

        Message message;
        while ((message = dlqConsumer.receive(1000)) != null) {
            try {
                log.debug("Processing: " + ((ObjectMessage) message).getObject());
                assert session.getTransacted();
                sender.send(message);
                assert session.getTransacted();
                session.commit();
                log.debug("resubmitted successfully to main queue from dlq");
            } catch (Exception jmse) {
                log.error("Exception caught while resubmitting message to main queue", jmse);
                session.rollback();
                throw jmse;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception caught while sending message", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        cleanUp(ctx, queueConn);
    }
}

Full stack trace
09 Nov 2024 08:26:39,160 ERROR [DLQService] Exception caught while resubmitting message to main queue
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: MQJMSRA_DS4001: commit():Illegal for a non-transacted Session:sessionId=7622785546896845312
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectSession._checkTransactedState(DirectSession.java:1015) ~[imqjmsra.jar:?]
    at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectSession.commit(DirectSession.java:242) ~[imqjmsra.jar:?]
    at com.crlcorp.cls.toxde.services.DLQService.resubmitMessages(DLQService.java:124) [toxde-ejb-7.1.3-SNAPSHOT_jar/:?]
    at com.crlcorp.cls.toxde.sessionbeans.ToxDataEntrySessionBean.resubmitDLQMessages(ToxDataEntrySessionBean.java:462) [toxde-ejb-7.1.3-SNAPSHOT_jar/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:588) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:408) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4835) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:665) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:834) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:615) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:888) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:833) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:375) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4807) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4795) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:205) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:123) [ejb-container.jar:?]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy408.resubmitDLQMessages(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:229) [glassfish-corba-orb.jar:?]
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:140) [glassfish-corba-orb.jar:?]
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226) [glassfish-corba-orb.jar:?]
    at com.crlcorp.cls.toxde.ejb._ToxDataEntryRemote_DynamicStub.resubmitDLQMessages(com/crlcorp/cls/toxde/ejb/_ToxDataEntryRemote_DynamicStub.java) [?:?]
    at com.crlcorp.cls.toxde.form.controller.DLQController.resubmitDLQMessages(DLQController.java:38) [DLQController.class:?]
    at com.crlcorp.cls.toxde.form.DLQForm.resubmitMessage(DLQForm.java:55) [DLQForm.class:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
    at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:160) [jakarta.el.jar:3.0.4.payara-p1]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:261) [jakarta.el.jar:3.0.4.payara-p1]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:237) [jakarta.el.jar:3.0.4.payara-p1]
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:3.1.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:3.1.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:3.1.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:3.1.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:3.1.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-osgi-bundle.jar:3.1.9.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:66) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:63) [myfaces-all-1.1.1.jar:?]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:222) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:847) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:1012) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:55) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451) [jakarta.faces.jar:2.3.14.payara-p3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1637) [web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:259) [web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:167) [web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:757) [web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:577) [web-core.jar:?]
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) [web-glue.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:158) [web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [web-core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:239) [web-core.jar:?]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520) [kernel.jar:?]
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217) [kernel.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:201) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549) [nucleus-grizzly-all.jar:?]


Is there perchance an active JTA transaction in progress when this method is invoked?

It appears you're operating in a Java EE container which changes JMS transaction semantics from a normal Java SE environment. The JavaDoc for Connection.createSession(boolean transacted, int acknowledgeMode) states:

In a Java EE web or EJB container, when there is an active JTA transaction in progress:

Both arguments transacted and acknowledgeMode are ignored. The session will participate in the JTA transaction and will be committed or rolled back when that transaction is committed or rolled back, not by calling the session's commit or rollback methods. Since both arguments are ignored, developers are recommended to use createSession(), which has no arguments, instead of this method.

In the Java EE web or EJB container, when there is no active JTA transaction in progress:

...
If transacted is set to true, then the JMS provider is recommended to ignore the specified parameters and instead provide a non-transacted, auto-acknowledged session. However the JMS provider may alternatively provide a local transacted session.
Applications are recommended to set transacted to false and acknowledgeMode to JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE or Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE since since applications which set transacted to false and set acknowledgeMode to JMSContext.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, or which set transacted to true, may not be portable.


It appears to me that your Java EE environment is behaving as described here. In other words, it is ultimately ignoring the fact that your Session is transacted.

I removed the commit, but it won't read any DLQ messages unless I have queueConn.start().  If I call queueConn.close() it throws a RollbackException when the method returns.  Any idea why?

The JMS API requires you to call Connection.start() in order to consume messages given the way you're creating the Connection instance so the behavior you're seeing in that respect is expected. Regarding the RollbackException, I recommend you ask a new question as it's not clear what's happening. Lastly, if my answer addressed your question please accept it to help other users who have this same question in the future. Thanks!

The answer to the rollback was I needed to create a copy of the message.  Apparently is not allowed.
ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
Message copyMessage = session.createObjectMessage(objectMessage.getObject());
sender.send(copyMessage);
